# Switch between different layouts

Tags: android

I want to add I kind of status bar to my app.
The status bar should indicate the status of an external device.
If the device is not connected, there should be just some text, but if it is connected, there should be some informations about the device. Also the background color of that bar should change.

My thoughts were, just to create two layouts to switch between, instead of changing attributes and visibilities of each item.

Is this the preferred way? How to best switch between these two?

Comment: To get better next time, why is this question downvoted? Bad question? oO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to define two separate layout files, as the UI is completely different for both the cases. and have a ViewGroup like FrameLayout as a container and when connection state changes, inflate the respective layout and add it to the container(remove all the views from the container before adding).

To optimize further, if the connection state change can occur often, then the inflated view can be stored locally and check for null before inflating the view. do not inflate if you already inflated before and just update the content of the views in that case.

Comment: This works pretty good. But instead of inflating the layouts programmatically, I've added both versions of the status bar to the framelayout with include tags. Later in code I just switch the visibility.

Comment: Can be done that way as well But inflating required layout programatically is kind of further optimization,  as it will not required to inflate un used layouts/views. Like if there is not change in the connection state, then also both the layouts inflated if added both statically. But in the other case it will inflate only one. Ofcourse, its just an optimization and may/may not be adopted on need basis.  You can accept the answer if you like. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `ViewAnimator`:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html

You can have defined more layouts and switching easily using methods:

```
viewAnimator.showNext(); 
viewAnimator.showPrevious(); 
viewAnimator.setDisplayedChild(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing attributes is the preferred way.For every condition we should not create different layouts and then restart activity to incorporate that layout.

Comment: But the "two" status bars should contain completly different elements (labels, ...)? Should I really make them all visible/invisible on connection state?

Comment: Create 2 status bars in a single layout file and make that parent layout gone/visible depending upon the situation.Every label/view need not be displayed/hidden